# Entity Framework - One-way one-to-one relation

Tags: entity-framework

I need to make a one-to-one relation between two tables, but only one-way.

```
[Accounts]
account_id  
name  
etc...

[SalesReps]
sales_rep_id  
account_id
account
etc...
```

So, I want the SalesReps table to have a relation to Accounts, but I don't want Accounts to have a reference to SalesReps.

I tried this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<sales_rep>()
.HasRequired(a => a.account)
.WithMany()
.HasForeignKey(a => a.account_id);
```

But that gives me:

> sales_rep_account_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'sales_rep_account_Source' in relationship 'sales_rep_account'. Because the Dependent Role refers to the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '1'.

Comment: Do you have Roles associated with your SalesReps table?

Comment: Please provide the relevant part of the entity model in question (C# code - class, properties rather than just names). Essentially [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

The way you do this is with WithRequiredDependent() configuration. Your entities will be:

```
public class Account
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class SalesRep
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public Account Account { get; set; }
}
```

In OnModelCreating() method you should do this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Account>().HasKey(x => x.Id);
modelBuilder.Entity<SalesRep>().HasKey(x => x.Id);
modelBuilder.Entity<SalesRep>().HasRequired(x => x.Account).WithRequiredDependent().Map(x => x.MapKey("AccountId"));
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, that all I had to do was:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<sales_rep>()
            .HasRequired(a => a.account)
            .WithOptional();
```